# How to loop with repeated values within a variable?

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, glm

I have a dataset called `bjmd` that looks like this (simplified):

```
      rte   year   y  obs
22037 46001  1     0   1
22042 46001  2     4   3
22047 46001  3     5   3
22202 46002  1    11   1
22207 46002  2    14   1
22212 46002  3     6   1
22140 46003  1     5   6
22141 46003  2     2   6
22142 46003  3     6   6
```

I want to run a loop to conduct a `glm` analysis for each distinct `rte` (46001,46002, 46003). Within each `rte`, there are multiple `year`s and they all need to be included in the `glm` analysis. From each route's `glm` test, I am taking the slope and creating another table with route and slope as columns. This is what I want it to look like:

```
rte    slope
46001   x
46002   y
46003   z
```

Here is the for loop code I came up with:

```
route<-with(bjmd,unique(rte))
slope<-with(bjmd,numeric(length(unique(rte))))
table<-data.frame(route,slope)
for (i in unique(as.factor(bjmd$rte))) {
  data<-subset(bjmd, rte=='i')
  slope[i] <- coef(summary(glm(y ~  year+obs,
                               family = poisson(link=log),data=data)))[2,1]
  table[i,2] <-paste(slope[i])
})
table
```

Something is wrong with this code as I keep getting 0 values for my slope:

```
  route slope
1 46001     0
2 46002     0
3 46003     0
```

Can somebody please help point out where I am messing it up?

Comment: You need to remove the quotes around `i` from `data<-subset(bjmd, rte=='i')`. At present, you're subsetting values equal to the character string `'i'`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No looping is needed; just use `split` to split your dataset into groups according to `rte`. Then fit a model to each group with `lapply`.

```
lapply(split(bjmd, bjmd$rte), function(dat) glm(y ~ year + obs, data=dat))
```

You could also model everything in one go, with an interaction term. The predicted values will be the same, but the residual deviance, df and hence P-values will be different. Which approach is better suited to your needs depends on your project.

```
glm(y ~ (year + obs) * factor(rte), data=bjmd)
```